# CFUUID shared between iPhone and iPad for a given user - how? / why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have an iOS app that is used by end-users on both their iPhones and iPads.

For each specific installation, if a UUID has not been previously generated and stored, the following code to generate a UUID for each app installation (i.e. by device), and persisted on that device.

```
// Need to initialise the UUID

CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

if (theUUID) 
{
    NSString *tempUniqueID = [NSMakeCollectable(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID)) autorelease];

    CFRelease(theUUID);

    // Save to Prefs

   ...
}
```

The app then registers on my Server, submitting the generated UUID as a unique identifier for this installation, along with some other app fields.  The UUID is never passed back to the device / app from the Server.

However, I am seeing that for a single user, their devices are reporting the same UUID on both their iPhone and iPads (but not in all cases, most user's, devices report different UUIDs on their iPhone and iPad).

Is there some circumstance where the same UUID would be reported for a given user on both their iPhone and iPad?

Thanks.

Comment: 'Along with some other app fields' sound suspect. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Something else must be wrong. You could call `CFUUIDCreate` a billion times (literally) on both devices and no two results would be the same.

Comment: Why don't you create an id based on user's login credentials and device type. This way you can identify the user and the device + this will give you valuable stats at a later point of time

Comment: @duci9y : the app registers the installed app build number (so I know which version the device is running), the user assigned to that device, the APNS token, etc, but the UUID is used as the key.

Comment: I checked in case NSUserDefaults are synced across devices - they aren't unless specifically developed to do so via iCloud.  The app doesn't do that.